# Vue material - I don't see changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I am using http://vuematerial.io/#/getting-started in my vue project (webpack, hot reloads, babel and so on).

I've imported this library (via npm) and included it in main.js file hovewer i don't see any changes in my project. The browser doesnt render it.

What am i doing wrong?

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)

Vue.material.registerTheme('default', {
  primary: 'blue',
  accent: 'red',
  warn: 'red',
  background: 'grey'
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: 'body'
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <hello></hello>
    <md-button>Default</md-button> // this doesnt work!
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {
    'hello': Hello,
    'documents': Documents,
    'Home': Home
  },
  data: function () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you include an error messages you get in the terminal.

Comment: I don't get any error messages. Babel compiler don't see any errors. All is included correctly.

Comment: what is your page source? For debugging I suggest you this to add new `Vue({}); `    this: `beforeUpdate: function() {
      console.debug('vue rerendering');
      console.debug(this);
    },
    beforeCreate: function() {
      console.debug('vue creating');
      console.debug(this);
    }, `

Can you show me where you inject the vue app into the html? Maybe the vue can not find its div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried terminating the job in node and serving again? I havent used vue-material myself but I find this issue cropped up a few times while I was dabbling in vue.

Comment: Yes. I terminated many times node server as well django server (which serves back end files). I am working on that 3 days...

Answer (score 0):

Is your vue-material.css being imported correctly?

Try changing `import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material'` to `import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'`

I can't tell from your question if this is your problem or whether you are having problems with the hot reloading.  Might try to describe what you see in the browser.